# TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/ index.html

Tags: python, django

I am doing a tutorial about django project.
Actually it is 4.51 in the morning and i want to just make it work.

My urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/$', 'polls.views.index'),
)
```

My views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

In the folder templates I have index.html file.
It showed me the same `TemplateDoesNotExist` error, so I did some research and 
[I found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037232/django-tutorial-templatedoesnotexist-at-polls)
so I've added to my settings.py this code:

```
import os.path
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/'),
)
```

So how to make it work??

This is the traceback:

> ```
>     Environment:
>
>
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
>
> Django Version: 1.6.1
> Python Version: 3.3.3
> Installed Applications:
> ('django.contrib.admin',
>  'django.contrib.auth',
>  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>  'django.contrib.sessions',
>  'django.contrib.messages',
>  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>  'polls')
> Installed Middleware:
> ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Template Loader Error:
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
> Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
> C:\Users\JD\PycharmProjects\MyDjangoApp\MyDjangoApp\templates\index.html
> ```
>
> (File does not exist)
>       Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>       C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html
>   (File does not exist)
>       C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html
>   (File does not exist)
>
> ```
> Traceback:
> File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
>   114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\JD\PycharmProjects\MyDjangoApp\polls\views.py" in index
>   8.     return render_to_response('index.html')
> File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py" in render_to_response
>   29.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
> File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
>   162.         t = get_template(template_name)
> File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
>   138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
> File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in find_template
>   131.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
>
> Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/
> Exception Value: index.html
> ```

Comment: is there a file located at: `C:\Users\JD\PycharmProjects\MyDjangoApp\MyDjangoApp\templates\index.html`?

Comment: Nope there is twice MyDjangoApp in the path but i have just once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
import os.path
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

to

```
import os
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

If you look at your traceback, Python is looking for a template folder within your app folder, I assume that it would be the same folder as settings.py.

Another approach is to copy your templates folder into MyDjangoAPP folder.

Comment: DO u mean, I can copy template folder to MyDjangoApp folder and don't write in setting.py anything like above?

Comment: Yup! That would also mean that every time you create a new app you'd have to create a new templates folder for this specific app and place that apps templates in your newly created templates folder.

For example:

\MyDjangoApp\app1\templates
 and 
\MyDjangoApp\app2\templates