# django Templates does not exists execpt home url

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, virtualenv

I am creating a simple website.and having kinda odd error `TemplateDoesNotExist at /about/` but my `homepage` working fine without TempaletDoesNotExist error. mine both `home.html` and `about.html` in same `directory` and I tried many solutions with the reference of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741762/templatedoesnotexist-at-polls-index-html) 
the actual problem is one URL is working and another one is not. please help me out thanks

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /about/

about.hmtl

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://www.appname./about/
Django Version:     2.2.9
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

about.hmtl

Exception Location:     /home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  /home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/bin/python3.5_bin
Python Version:     3.5.7
Python Path:    

['/home/name/appname',
 '/opt/passenger-5.3.7-4.el6.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts',
 '/home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/lib64/python35.zip',
 '/home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/lib64/python3.5',
 '/home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux',
 '/home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/alt/python35/lib64/python3.5',
 '/opt/alt/python35/lib/python3.5',
 '/home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 3 May 2020 04:48:46 +0000

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/about.hmtl (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/name/virtualenv/appname/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/about.hmtl (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/name/appname/mysite/templates/about.hmtl (Source does not exist)
```

My templates<`dir`>

```
/home/name/appname/mysite/templates/home.html
/home/name/appname/mysite/templates/about.html
```

app<`views.py`>

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request,template_name='home.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request=request,template_name='about.hmtl')
```

app<`urls.py`>

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "bugengine"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    url(r'^about/',views.about, name="about"),
]
```

---

`setting.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in your `views.py` file in about view. Spell `about.html` instead of `about.hmtl`. 
And that's it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote *about.hmtl* instead of *html*...just correct that :)